# Add two values in different rows in ggplot as text

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I have this dataset:
structure(list(new = c("No: 0.91", "Yes: 0.89", "All: 0.84")), row.names = c(NA,
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
And I would like to create a plot with only the text like:
[image]

But the text to be one below the other. So you have any idea?

Comment: Have a look at `geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `nudge_y` to shift the labels:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(
    x = 1, y = 1,
    label = c("No: 0.91", "Yes: 0.89", "All: 0.84")
  ), nudge_y = .05 * c(1, 0, -1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to specify the y axis positions manually within `aes`

```r
ggplot(dataset, aes(0, -seq_along(new) + 2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = new, color = new)) +
  ylim(c(-2, 2)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1', guide = 'none')
```

[image]